# Laravel Seeder Stuck no progress

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-7, laravel-seeding

I have this on my DatabaseSeeder

```
$this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
    $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    $this->call(MemberSeeder::class);
    $this->call(MemberUserSeeder::class);
```

I tried it once and successfully done but after checking the database it has no data.

Now when I try to run it again, it stuck on this forever

```
Seeding: RolesTableSeeder
```

and no progress it is almost 5mins or more and nothing happens.. Please help

```
    Role::truncate();
    Role::create(['name' => 'superadmin']);
    Role::create(['name' => 'logistics']);
    Role::create(['name' => 'logistics_staff']);
    Role::create(['name' => 'reports']);
    Role::create(['name' => 'finance']);
    Role::create(['name' => 'finance_staff']);
    Role::create(['name' => 'member_admin']);
    Role::create(['name' => 'member_agent']);
    Role::create(['name' => 'member_manager']);
    Role::create(['name' => 'member']);
```

Comment: Show the roles table seeder?

Comment: @mrhn I already added but it works fine before. it just happen like this and I do not know why even if I do composer update.

Comment: How is this related to Composer?